# How to write fitted model using data from R?

Tags: r, regression, reporting

[image: data from R]

I don't know how to write a fitted model. What I did was:
Y hat = (1.222 * e^1) + (3.938 * e^-4 * sqft_living)

This is for the fitted model for waterfront = 0 group. However, I don't know how to do it for waterfront = 1 group? Can someone please give me some advice on this?

Comment: Hello Mary, you look really close to your goal. Is your problem in interpreting the `sqft_living:waterfront` interaction term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `sqft_living` is a numerical variable then we have

For `waterfront` = 0 then

```
Y <- 12.22 + 0.0003938*sqft_living
```

For `waterfront` = 1 then

```
Y <- 12.22 + 0.000393*sqft_living + 0.7814 + 0.00004796*sqft_living
```

The main effect for `sqft_living` can be interpreted as the increase in the outcome (ie the slope) associated with a 1 unit increase in `sqft_living` when `waterfront` is zero.

The main effect for `waterfront` can be interpreted as the difference in the intercepts (the value of the outcome when `sqft_living` is zero) between the two groups

The interaction can be interpreted as the difference in slope between the 2 groups.

It might be a good idea to centre the `sqft_living` variable if a zero value for `sqft_living` is not meaningful , and possibly rescale it (so that the estimate is not too small)